# How can JMX in embedded glassfish be activated?

Tags: maven, jmx, glassfish-3, glassfish-embedded

how can one activate JMX in embedded glassfish (using maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to provide proper `domain.xml` to plugin:

```
<configuration>
  <configFile>${basedir}/domain.xml</configFile>
</configuration>
```

Default one has JMX inactive.